# div padding, margin?

Tags: html, css, border, margin

I am a iPhone developer stuck with some basic CSS properties ;) 
I want to show something like this:
[image]

This is what I have:

```
<div class="cell">
    <div class="cell_3x3_top">
        <div class="cell_3x3_type rounded_left">type</div> <!--UPDATED:2010/09/29-->
        <div class="cell_3x3_title rounded_right">title</div><!--UPDATED:2010/09/29-->
    </div>
    <div class="cell_3x3_content rounded_left rounded_right">content</div><!--UPDATED:2010/09/29-->
</div>
```

and the css:

```
div.cell_3x3_top{
    height:20%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 1px; /*to compensate space between top and content*/
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;


}
div.cell_3x3_type{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin-right: -2px; /*UPDATED:2010/09/29*/
}
div.cell_3x3_title{
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    background-color: inherit;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;  /* maybe not neccesary*/
    padding: 0 0 0 0; /*maybe not neccesary*/
    margin-left: -1px; /*UPDATED:2010/09/29 */

}
div.cell_3x3_content{
    height:80%;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

But when I render my content with above code `title` div seems to be too large and it appears underneath `type` div, Why is this?
`type` div is 20% width, `title` is 80% width so it should be 100% exactly. Is any margin or other metric I am forgetting here?
I have tried to move `title` div to the left using margin but is still buggy. I wonder what is the correct way of getting something like the picture?
(Not exactly because if you look closer `title` div is a little bit shorter than it should be. See that its right border is not aligned with `content` div.)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 2010/09/28

This is actually what I want to achieve:
[image]

and this is what I have:
[image]

Above code (updated a little bit) would work if I wouldn't have bordered divs. Since border width is 1px what I need is to set `type` div width to 20%-2px (left border + right border = 2px) and `title` div to 80%-2px

```
.rounded_left{
    border-top-left-radius: 4px 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px 4px;

    border-color:gray;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

(.rounded_right is similar)

This is not related to `clear:both` property I believe. I tried and didn't had any effect since my `content` div was good form the beginning.

In short: How can I make a div including its border to be let's say exactly 20% width?

Ignacio

ANSWER:

I realized that a wrapper div around type and title respectively solves the problem. So my answer is kind of like this:

```
<td class="cell">
<div class="cell_3x3_top bordered">
<div class="cell_3x3_type_container"><div class="cell_3x3_type rounded_left full_height">6</div></div>
<div class="cell_3x3_title_container"><div class="cell_3x3_title rounded_right full_height">title</div></div>                                                               </div>
<div class="cell_3x3_content rounded_left rounded_right">content</div>
</td>
```

I set 20% and 80% in the containers and the borders in the inner div.

Comment: That didn't solved my problem so I used tables in the end. And since HTML was too slow I implemented my stuff with CALayers instead of using UIWebView only for this view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing a clearing div. The floating elements do not expand the `.cell_3x3_type` div as you would expect. Try this instead:

```
<div class="cell">
    <div class="cell_3x3_top">
        <div class="cell_3x3_type">type</div>
        <div class="cell_3x3_title">title</div>
        <div class="cell_3x3_clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell_3x3_content">content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.cell_3x3_clear  {
  clear: both;
}
```

The rest remains the same.

**EDIT:**
A small explanation of what the clear property does: consider a container `div` that contains only floated elements, like this (using inline CSS for clarity):

```
<div id="container" style="border: 1px solid green;">
  <div style="float: left; height: 30px; width: 30px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
  <div style="float: left; height: 20px; width: 20px; border: 1px solid blue;"></div>
</div>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [fii.cz](http://fii.cz/vksyr))</sub>

The height of the container `div` is 0 because the floating elements are taken out of the document flow and do not affect the height of their container anymore. The `clear: both` property on an element "clears" all floats, i.e. makes sure that the element is placed below all floating elements that precede it:

```
<div style="float: left; height: 30px; width: 30px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
<div style="float: left; height: 20px; width: 20px; border: 1px solid blue;"></div>
<div style="clear: both; height: 10px; width: 50px; border: 1px solid black;">Cleared</div>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [fii.cz](http://fii.cz/tjdqwac))</sub>

If you combine the two above examples, you can force the container div to have its height equal to the height of the highest floating element in it:

```
<div id="container" style="border: 2px solid green;">
  <div style="float: left; height: 30px; width: 30px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
  <div style="float: left; height: 20px; width: 20px; border: 1px solid blue;"></div>
  <div style="clear: both; height: 0px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
</div>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [fii.cz](http://fii.cz/nmpshuh))</sub>

Comment: I have googled clear property but I couldn't find a good explanation. Would you explain what clear property exactly does and why do I need it here? Thanks;)

Comment: Updated my post, hopefully it's understandable :)

Comment: I tried that but I didn't work ;( I have updated my question also, please take a look at it. ;)

Comment: Took a look at it and you cannot really solve that reliably using divs. Just use tables, they are perfect for your situation - the maintenance will be easier, the layout will be simpler and the semantics shouldn't be hit much as the page looks like a table.

Comment: Even though I couldn't 100% solution you adviced me and pointed the usage of Tables which is what I ended doing. Thanks